# Image of $S^1$ through $f(z)=\frac{-c}{a+bz}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am confusing about the following problem: Let $a,b,c>0$ and $f(z)=\dfrac{-c}{bz+a}$. If $a\neq b$, what can we say about the image of $|z|=1$ through the mapping $f$? Is it a circle?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It is a general fact that Möbius transformations take generalized circles to generalized circles. Hence, the image of $\{|z| = 1\}$ will either be a circle or a line in the plane; the details depend on the particular values of $a, b, c$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the image is a circle, since it doesn't contain $\infty$:
$$f^{-1}(\infty) = \frac{-a}{b} \notin S^1.$$